# Need help to find python code bug

Tags: python

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  i = 0
  while i < len(nums):
     if nums[i] == nums[i+1]: 
        nums.remove(nums[i])
        i = i + 1
     else: i = i + 1
  return nums
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Who can tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:` is were you will get index error for the last element.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code.

As AbhiP points out, you're looking at pairs of consecutive items in your list - there are `len(nums)-1` pairs that you should be comparing, but you're trying to compare `len(nums)` pairs.  That's one cause of the index error.

Secondly, as John mentions, you're removing items in your list while you loop through it.  If you really want to keep your current structure, you need to **not** increment the loop variable when you remove an item.

**Correction/Clarification**: This second point won't cause an index error, but it will cause bugs by making the code skip the evaluation of certain pairs, e.g. for inputs such as `[1, 1, 1, 2]`.

Taking these two points into consideration, your code will look like:

```
i = 0
while i < len(nums) - 1:
    if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
        nums.remove(nums[i])
    else:
        i += 1
```

Which will remove the index error.

Thirdly, `nums.remove(nums[i])` will also cause non-index error bugs.  Try the above code with `nums` being `[1, 2, 3, 1, 1]`.  You will see that the first `1` is removed, not the 4th or 5th item in the list.  This is because `remove` on a list gets rid of the first instance that appears in the list.  You should probably do `del` instead, as below:

```
i = 0
while i < len(nums) - 1:
    if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
        del nums[i]
    else:
        i += 1
```

Finally, while not a bug, best practice would suggest that you shouldn't modify a list while looping through it - this makes the code hard to reason about, and can lead to subtle bugs.  Instead it's usually better if you just create a new list and return that.

```
new_nums = []
for i in range(len(new_nums)-1):
    if nums[i] != nums[i+1]:
        new_nums.append(nums[i])
new_nums.append(nums[-1])
```

An alternative way of writing this using `zip` and list comprehensions, two of Python's cool features:

```
new_nums = [item1 for item1, item2 in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if item1 != item2]
new_nums.append(nums[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the line `while i < len(nums):`. It will iterate from 0 till `len-1` but the next line you are doing `if nums[i] == nums[i+1]` so the index will go until `len`.

Change it to:

```
while i < len(nums) - 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing items from the list while iterating through it. The for loop has no idea that the bounds have changed, thus the error.